# How to enable GCP service agent account via Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I understand there is a difference between a **[service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts)** and a **[service agent](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-agents)** for different services such as composer.

How do you enable a service agent via terraform?

What I'm trying to do is this :

```
# TODO : Maybe enable this service agent somehow via gcloud? It got enabled when trying to manually create the composer env from the console
# Step  4 (Src2) - Host project GKE service account: service-<some-numeric-id>@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
# Need 'container.serviceAgent' in the host project
resource "google_project_iam_member" "dev-omni-orch-gke-project-lvl-roles-t2" {
  provider = google.as_super_admin
  for_each = toset([
    "roles/container.serviceAgent",
  ])
  role   = each.value
  member = "serviceAccount:service-<some-numeric-id>@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  # member  = "serviceAccount:service-${google_project.main-shared-vpc-host.number}@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  # project = google_project.dev-main-code-base.project_id
  project = google_project.main-shared-vpc-host.project_id
}
```

I get

```
 Request `Create IAM Members roles/container.serviceAgent serviceAccount:service-<some-numeric-id>@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com for project "<shared-vpc-host-project-id>"` returned error: Batch request and retried single request "Create IAM Members roles/container.serviceAgent serviceAccount:service-<some-numeric-id>@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com for project \"<shared-vpc-host-project-id>\"" both failed. Final error: Error applying IAM policy for project "<shared-vpc-host-project-id>": Error setting IAM policy for project "<shared-vpc-host-project-id>": googleapi: Error 400: Service account service-<some-numeric-id>@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not exist., badRequest
```

But when I try to do it via the console manually, there is a prompt that asks me if I want to enable this service agent, which I do, but I want to be able to do this on terraform.

The said prompt :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service-[PROJECT_ID]@cloudcomposer-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com service agent will only exist after the Cloud Composer API has been enabled.

This can be done in Terraform using the [google_project_service resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_service), for example:

```
resource "google_project_service" "project" {
  project = "your-project-id"
  service = "composer.googleapis.com"
}
```

Once the API has been enabled, the service agent should exist and you should be able to grant it the required permissions.

Comment: I validated your response but it is important to specify that it is a service agent account.

Comment: Yes. There is only 1 "Cloud Composer API Service Agent" per project which has the "service-[PROJECT_NUMBER]@cloudcomposer-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com" email address. This service agent only exists after enabling the relevant API. The agent mentioned in your original answer is the "Kubernetes Engine Service Agent". So you may need to enable the Kubernetes Engine API as well for this to work. In general, service agents only exist once the relevant API has been enabled.